# Showing that matrix $M=\left[\begin{array}{c|c} AA^t & 2b\\\hline 0^t & 1\end{array}\right]$ is positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I have the following matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1) x (n+1)}$:

$M=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
AA^t & 2b \\
\hline
0^t & 1
\end{array}
\right]$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n x n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n \neq \vec 0$.

I want to prove that if A is non-singular and $||A^-1 b||_2^2 < 1$ $\Rightarrow M$ is positive definite.

I started by taking a non-zero $\vec v = (x, \alpha)$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and doing block product $x^t M x$. That yields the following equation:

$x^t M x = \alpha^2 + \alpha (2 x^t b) + x^t A A ^t x$.

For $M$ to be positive definite: $x^t M x > 0$, so if that quadratic equation is always positive the implication would hold.

I take its discriminant:

$b^2 - 4ac = 4 [(x^t b)^2 + x^t A A ^t x] = x^t (b - AA^tx)$.

And at that point I'm stuck. Is there a way of rewriting $||A^-1 b||_2^2$ in order to use it in that equation that I'm missing? Or is this a dead end?

Comment: I just realized that $A A^t = A^t A$. That would allow to rewrite $x^t A A^t x$ as  $(Ax)^t (Ax) = ||Ax||_2^2$.

Comment: $AA^t = A^t A$ does not hold in general. But you can always write $x^t AA^t x = \|A^t x\|_2^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I confused that property with the one that states that both of those products are _symmetric_.

Comment: Your matrix is not even Hermitian or symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You computed the discriminant incorrectly.
$$4(x^t b b^t x - x^t A A^t x)=4x^t (bb^t - AA^t)x = 4 x^t A((A^{-1} b)(A^{-1} b)^t - I) A^t x.$$

The matrix $(A^{-1} b)(A^{-1} b)^t - I$ is symmetric, so if we show all eigenvalues are negative, then this matrix is negative definite, so the above discriminant is negative, which would conclude the proof.

The eigenvalues of $(A^{-1} b)(A^{-1} b)^t - I$ can be obtained by taking eigenvalues of $(A^{-1} b)(A^{-1} b)^t$ and subtracting $1$.
Show that one eigenvalue of this latter matrix is $\|A^{-1} b\|_2$, and that the rest are zero.

---

More direct approach:

If $y$ and $v$ are vectors with $\|v\| < 1$, then Cauchy-Schwarz implies
$$y^t(vv^t - I)y = (v^t y)^2 - \|y\|^2 \le (\|v\|^2 - 1)\|y\|^2 < 0.$$
Do you see how to apply this to the original problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems like a simpler proof, but unfortunately I am not allowed to use eigenvalues.

Comment: @John See my edit.

Comment: I totally see it now. Thank you!